# How to bind the title of a form using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, data-binding

I am creating a form using angularjs and phpmailer. The input fields are binding and sending correctly, however, i am struggling to grab the title of the form, which is pretty important as the form will be a "service type" request.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ContactCtrl">
     <form ng-submit="submit(contactForm)" name="contactForm" method="post" class="service-form form-horizontal" role="form">
     <h3 ng-model="formData.serviceName" id="serviceName">Request for {{ details.name }}</h3>
     <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactForm.inputName.$invalid && submitted }">
     <input ng-model="formData.inputName" type="text" class="inputText text-input" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactForm.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
     <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="inputText text-input" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactForm.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
     <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Please add your requirements as per the 'Best Practice Checklist'"></textarea>
     </div>
     <button class="btn default btn-cancel" type="submit" onclick="switcher()">Cancel</button>
     <button class="btn default" type="submit">Send</button>
     </form>
     <p ng-class="result">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
'use strict';

$scope.result = 'hidden'
$scope.resultMessage;
$scope.formData;
$scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
$scope.submitted = false;

$scope.submit = function(contactform) {

    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    if (contactform.$valid) {
        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/forms/contact.php',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }
        $http(request).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data) {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-success';
                $scope.resultMessage = 'Thanks for the message! We will be in touch very soon.';
                $scope.formData = {};
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
                $scope.resultMessage = 'Ooops! Something went wrong, Please fill out all the fields.';
            }

        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.resultMessage = 'Ooops! Something went wrong, Please fill out all the fields.';
        $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
    }
}
```

}]);

so currently, I've got an h3 and have tried several other options, but the details.name isn't sending out, any help on this would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Can you show your controller as well? What do you want to happen? You shouldn't need to use `ng-model` if you just want to send a value from javascript to html.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Comment: the form should fire out the name, email and title of the form so the recipient can see what service has been requested. what do you think is best for this?